# How to implement a queue that sorts items by a given priority?

Tags: python, heap

I don't understand the arguments passed to `heappush`. Why negative priority?

```
import heapq 

class PriorityQueue: 
    def __init__(self): 
         self._queue = [] 
         self._index = 0

    def push (self, item, priority): 
        heapq.heappush (self._queue,(-priority, self._index, item))
        self._index += 1
```

Comment: It'll reverse the priority, so elements previously with higher priorities will now have low priorities.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what meaning is given to `priority`.

[Wikipedia on Priority queue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Priority_queue#Operations) has this:

> - *pull_highest_priority_element*: remove the element from the queue that has the *highest* priority, and return it.

and it includes this piece of code in its naive implementation of the `pull` operation:

```java
if highest.priority < node.priority {
    highest = node
}
```

So this Wikipedia article assumes that the node with the *greatest* value for `priority` should be pulled from the queue first.

This seems also to be the assumption made by the author of the code you have included in your question. The negation is needed because a Python's `heapq` module implements a min-heap, which will pull the node with the *least* value, not the *greatest*. That is the reason why the code negates the priority when pushing the node unto the heap.

The above-quoted Wikipedia article recognises that there is also an other convention:

> **Some conventions reverse the order of priorities, considering lower values to be higher priority**, so this may also be known as "get_minimum_element", and is often referred to as "get-min" in the literature.

If this would be the convention for your `Priority` class, then you would not negate the priority.

On a final note: Python also has [`queue.PriorityQueue`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/queue.html), and it uses the latter convention: lesser values will be pulled first. So that implementation would not do the same as your code.